# Is it possible to do one to many relation through the pivot in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So basically I have the relation many to many: every user can have many bets, and each  bet can have many users. The problem appears when I need to show all bets for user in the table. Some of bets user can check so I need to change row color. Is it possible somehow in simple way to get all bets and relation only if it exists for current user?

Something like:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\User\User::class)->withTimestamps();
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\User\User::class)->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->withTimestamps(); // here a need to retrieve first so that it be like $bets[1]->user
}
```

Comment: So you only want to list all the bets of the current user?

Comment: @GerardReches no, i need to show all the bets and assign only the current user to ->user if users exists